# How do I Unit Test and mock a C project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Project written in Visual Studio 2019 in C. I wish to Unit Test individual parts of my code and also be able to mock some functions off. What is the best way to go about this?

I have tried creating a new Unit Test Project within the same Solution as my production code, in the Native Unit Test framework for C++ in Visual Studio. The problem is I have to include my library files in every Unit Test project that I make which becomes tedious. I have tried the Fake Function Framework for C, but was unable to make it work.

I am open to new ideas, however it has to be in Visual Studio since my production code is placed in a project in Visual Studio.

Edit: A picture of my Solution Structure is shown in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK4BO.png)
I have to include the library files from my productionCode project inside my unit test project before it will build.

Comment: On an absolute basis, how tedious is it to set up unit test projects? After all, you’d only generally have one per library.

Comment: You may just write functions for test cases and execute the test cases by calling those functions.

Comment: You don't have to include your library files in every Unit Test project.

Comment: The problem is if I wish to unit test a file which depends on 10 other files that need to be stubbed / mocked. How would I mock those files after the project has already been built?

Comment: @Kasper runtime mocking is possible using an interface (abstract class), combined with IoC or Dependency-injection (they are not the same, IoC simply means callback).

Comment: @Top-Master I have managed to get the files into my unit test project. So the files are now being built using the files in the project instead of using external library files. The problem is now when I try to create a fake function with the fake function framework: https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff I get an error saying "one or more multiply defined symbol", which makes sense since the project is building both the production file and test file now. How do I combat this?

Comment: @Kasper try to avoid using global functions, as they are not testable very good, as you noticed (now you have to remove original symbol from test's symbols). Use OOP to interface everything (for example, use `LoggerInterface` instead of `printf` directly). Dependency-Injection using `std::shared_ptr` takes some memory but remember that one *empty* Java class may take five times more memory, than one C++ class with 10 `shared_ptr` fields.

Comment: Many things can be called Dependency-Injection , but what I mean is, simply a `class`, which has fields of type `str::shared_ptr`, along with constructor taking as input said fields's value (but public getter and setter for field, instead of constructor, is okay too).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer to my own question, but what I ended up doing was splitting my large project into smaller components and then write unit tests for each component instead of including library files from the large project. This way I could fake off the dependencies using the Fake Function Framework.
Thanks for the help